# How to get row cursor with primary key android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I have a table with the following

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL( "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + "ID" + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
        COLUMN_TOPIC + " TEXT," + COLUMN_LOCATION + " TEXT)");
}
```

I am trying to get all the data at a given rowid

```
public void getRowCursor(int position){
    SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
    
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " +
                "ID" + "=" + String.valueOf(position), null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    cursor.close
    //or
    
    Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME, null, "ID", new String[]{
        String.valueOf(position)},  null, null, null, null );
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    cursor.close
    database.close
}
```

I get an error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 1 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters.
```

I did populate the table. How do I return a cursor based on the position of entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I return a cursor based on the position of entry

First, your method `getRowCursor()` should return a `Cursor`.
Also, you should not close the returned cursor because I assume that you want to use its results somehow.

Your code with the method `rawQuery()` should work like this:

```
public Cursor getRowCursor(int position) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE ID = " + String.valueOf(position);
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(sql, null);
    // cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor;
}
```

But, the safe and recommended way to pass parameters to a query is with `?` placeholders instead of concatenating them inside the sql statement and passing them as array items in the 2nd argument of `rawQuery()`:

```
public Cursor getRowCursor(int position) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE ID = ?";
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(sql, new String[] {String.valueOf(position)});
    // cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor;
}
```

Note that `moveToFirst()` moves the cursor's index at the 1st row of the cursor (if it exists).
I commented out this call, because you should use it after you call `getRowCursor()` like this:

```
Cursor cursor = getRowCursor(10); // or any other ID
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {  // the cursor contains at least 1 row
    ....
} else {  // the cursor is empty
    ....
}
```

and when you are done with the cursor:

```
cursor.close();
```